# Is RegEx used by System.Net.Mail.MailAddress

Tags: c#, regex, email, email-validation

I have been trying to find a good RegEx for email validation.

I have already gone through [Comparing E-mail Address Validating Regular Expressions](http://fightingforalostcause.net/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php) and that didn't suffice all my validation needs.
I have Google/Bing(ed) and scan the top 50 odd results including regular expressions info article and other stuff.

So finally i used the `System.Net.Mail.MailAddress` class to validate my email address. Since, if this fails, my email won't get sent to the user.

I want to customize the validation as used by the constructor of the class.

So how do I go ahead and get the validation/RegEx that the MailAddress class is using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Reflector... forgot you were still free!

Reflected the System.Net.Mail.MailAddress...

Found that it used a `void ParseValue(string address)`

and `void GetParts(string address)` methods to primary check the mail address format.

//Edited

Surprised, no RegEx was involved!

Comment: Here's the source code use for parsing http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/mail/MailAddressParser.cs

Answer (score 3):

No it does not use a RegEx, but rather a complicated process that would take way too long to explain here. How do I know? I looked at the implementation using the .NET Reflector. And so can you :D

http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/ (it's free)

Comment: Exactly what I just did too! I would go with some sort of standard for your Regex -- likely found in one of the 50 odd results you looked at.

Comment: Thanks a ton guys! Just forgot reflector still existed and MS didnt obfuscate its code like other API vendors do. :)

Comment: Here's the source code use for parsing http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/mail/MailAddressParser.cs

Answer (score 0):

According to the Reflector, the class doesn't use regular expressions at all.