# validation email

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Email Address Validation for ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182542/email-address-validation-for-asp-net)

```
 <input id="txtemail" type="text" />

 private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     //txtemail check is email or not
 }
```

how can check that content txtemail is email.

Comment: How about ASP.NET RegularExpression Validation control?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Read these posts:

- [Email Address Validation for ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182542/email-address-validation-for-asp-net)
- [Is RegEx used by System.Net.Mail.MailAddress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766668/is-regex-used-by-system-net-mail-mailaddress)

Others:

- [Effective Email Address Validation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/validation/Valid_Email_Addresses.aspx)
- [Email Address Validation Using Regular Expression](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/EmailRegexValidator.aspx)

Comment: This incorrectly classifies emails with plus signs in them as invalid. There's also probably some other flaws, too.

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you just use build-in [`System.Net.Mail.MailAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.aspx) class for email validation?

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool isValidEmail = false;
    try
    {
        var email = new MailAddress(txtEmail.Text);
        isValidEmail = true;
    {
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Note: as mentioned in the comments, it might give unexpected results. A mail address here is composed of a *User name*, *Host* name and optionally, a *DisplayName*. So, in this case you could additionaly verify the *DisplayName*, and if it is not empty also return `false`.

Comment: This might give unexpected results. For instance, given the string john doe@mail.com, this is considered to be valid email. Where doe@mail.com is the email and john the display name.

Comment: @coffeeyesplease: thank you, it is fair enough :) I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

in c#

take regular expresion validator and set its poperty "VALIDATION EXPRESION" via go in property window.

and put expesion is follow.

^([a-zA-Z0-9_-.]+)@(([[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9-]+.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(]?)$

try this..........

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use a [email validating regex](http://www.google.ca/search?q=C%23+email+validator+regex) to verify that the txtemail.text is a valid email. A word of caution though, if you are going to do this make sure to implement a robust solution as nothing chokes users more than when they enter a valid email and have the page reject it.